# isset and !empty for ajax posted variable retrieval php

Tags: php, ajax, variables, post

I have a button group consisting of two buttons, each assigned an id and a value :

```
echo "<div style='margin-top:20px;' class='btn-group'>
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' id='btnconventional' value='conventional' style=' border-radius: 3px;'>Conventional Units</button>
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' id='btnsi' value='si' style=' border-radius: 3px;'>SI Units</button>
</div>";
```

And then i want to submit a query and table result depending on the value of the button that will be sent via this ajax script :

```
<script>    
    $("#btnconventional").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",            
        data: { 
            Metric: $('#btnconventional').val(), // < note use of 'this' here                
        },
        success: function(result) {
            alert('Viewing conventional units');
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Now when i try to get the variable and run my code, nothing appears but the else statement:

```
if(isset($_POST['Metric']) && !empty($_POST['Metric'])){
    $sql2 = "Select DISTINCT Record_id,Test_Group,Test_Name,Result,subtests.Units from tests,medicalrecords,subtests WHERE medicalrecords.CommonID=".$comid." and medicalrecords.Subtest_id IS NOT NULL AND medicalrecords.Subtest_id=subtests.Subtest_id AND subtests.Test_id=tests.Test_id and tests.Test_Group='CBC'"; 
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    echo $_POST['Metric'];
    echo "<table style='margin-top:10px;' class='table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-condensed' width='100%' cellspacing='0'>
        <thead>
            <tr bgcolor='#d3d3d3'>
                <th style='text-align:center;'>CBC</th>
                <th style='text-align:center;'>Result</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>";
        while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
            echo "<tr>
                <td style='text-align:center;'>".$row2['Test_Name']."</td> 
                <td style='text-align:center;'>".$row2['Result']." ".$row2['Units']."</td>                                     
            </tr>";
        }
        echo "<tfoot>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tfoot>
    </table>";
    echo "<button onclick='hideLabResult();'>Back</button>";
}
else echo "Nope";
```

The success alert is showing after clicking the button, yet "Nope" still shows after the click, it's not going into the if statement and I can't seem to find out way, I'm a starter in ajax and I'd appreciate any tip or help please.

Comment: try putting Metric inside quotes eg `"Metric": $('#btnconventional').val(),`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, but i'm sure it works without quotes, because i've already tried on a different page a similar request but i've pulled results on top of the page with request method post and ran the query inside of that if and worked, but now i don't want to do it up in that scope only

Comment: Where is `$comid` set? Your also open to SQL injection.

Comment: @Lalati where did you put your script tags?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone at this stage i don't really care about SQL injection, i know i will have to use prepared statements, and $comid is retrieved through url at the start of my page because it was sent as get from another page and i don't think it has anything to do with the problem , i tried specifying it explicitly but still the same problem

Comment: @WebDegBrian after the div containing the if else statement

Comment: @Lalati have you included the config file?

Comment: @WebDegBrian Yep, i just made sure the request is successful and sending the variable Metric with value= "conventional" too, i really have no idea why the if condition is not being met

Comment: @Lalati what is the problem again? I’m not sure I got it. But its an interesting question

Comment: @WebDegBrian the problem is not being able to go into that if condition, after clicking on a button that send an ajax post request to the same page with the button's value, check the if statement in question's code section and how the variable is being sent in the script for more information

Answer (score 1):

So in success you are only registered to display information about a successful request, not its contents. To display its contents, use `$('.btn-group').html(result);` for jquery example.

Comment: Hello, i tried that and it returned all the page starting from the first tab, so now i ll work around specifying all that is inside my if, instead of "result", but on a different page i was able to retrieve the variable on top of the page using request method post {} , but i wanted to go outside of that scope

Answer (score -2):

well, when I run the code on my local , I found ajax was not sending the request to correct page. When I put *url* then success message was showing there with all html code(whole page I mean). Then I write *isset* condition on top of page and at ending of *}* i put *exit()*.
Now its working.

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['Metric']) && !empty($_POST['Metric'])) 
 {
  $sql2 = "Select DISTINCT Record_id,Test_Group,Test_Name,Result,subtests.Units from tests,medicalrecords,subtests WHERE medicalrecords.CommonID=".$comid." and medicalrecords.Subtest_id IS NOT NULL AND medicalrecords.Subtest_id=subtests.Subtest_id AND subtests.Test_id=tests.Test_id and tests.Test_Group='CBC'  "; 
  $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
  $html = $_POST['Metric'];

  $html.= "<table style='margin-top:10px;'  class='table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-condensed' width='100%' cellspacing='0'>
<thead>
   <tr bgcolor='#d3d3d3'>

    <th style='text-align:center;'>CBC</th>

    <th style='text-align:center;'>Result</th>
</tr>
</thead>";

 while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {

   $html.= "<tr>

        <td style='text-align:center;'>".$row2['Test_Name']."</td> 

        <td style='text-align:center;'>".$row2['Result']." ".$row2['Units']."</td>                                     
    </tr>"; 


  }
 $html .="<tfoot>

 <td></td>
 <td></td>
  </tfoot>
 </table>"; 

  $html .= "<button onclick='hideLabResult();'>Back</button>";
   echo $html;
  } else echo "Nope"; ?>


<script>
$("#btnconventional").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",

    data: { 
        Metric: $('#btnconventional').val(), // < note use of 'this' here

    },
    url : '', // put your page url
    success: function(result) {
        alert('Viewing conventional units'+result);
    },
    error: function(result) {
        alert('error');
    }
 });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Man, if you want to edit the code, please but some here, please try not to write like that, which causes a lot of problems for future readers

Comment: Priyanka, if we don't specify the url, it takes it as the current page, which i need, i already tried specifying it like you suggested but it was still the same

Comment: yes, but still on my local it was not sending there. so when I put url then it worked for me :)

Comment: Lalit, did you check requested url inside inspect element.?

Comment: The result you specified was what is being done inside the if statement? could you edit code and put your statement please

Comment: if statement is correct. problem : not passing the variable in correct address. as i found :)

Comment: @Priyanka yes the url is correct, and the data is being sent under Form data : Metric : conventional